# Dynamic number of list comprehension items

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get permutations of a variable number of strings in a list.. I'm sure this is possible in Haskell, I'm just having a hard time finding a reference for this,

I'm looking to be able to do this `[ [n1] ++ [n2] ++ etc | n1 <- {first string}, n2 <- {second string}, etc ]`

Where my list might be `["hey", "now"]`

and my output would look like this:

`["hn","ho","hw","en","eo","ew","yn","yo","yw"]`

How would I go about doing something like that?

Comment: Do you want brute force or elegant?

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria both? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
> sequence ["hey", "now"]
["hn","ho","hw","en","eo","ew","yn","yo","yw"]
```

`sequence` is very general, but on lists you can think of it as if it were defined as follows:

```
sequence :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
sequence [] = [[]]
sequence (x:xs) = [ y:ys | y <- x, ys <- sequence xs ]
```

The result above is sometimes called the "cartesian product" of a list of lists, since it is similar to that operation on sets.

Comment: Oh. That's much nicer.

Comment: The type and definition body of `sequence` here isn't quite right. The first binding in the comprehension is wrong.

Comment: @DavidYoung Thanks. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This only works for strings of length 2, but shows the desugaring of the list comprehension (since `return` is `concat` and `fmap` is `map`, if I recall).

Here's a brute force way of doing it (if you'd like to know a possible approach). If you'd like the clean version, please see [chi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35025023/2391244).

`concat $ map (\char1 -> map (\char2 -> char1:[char2]) string2) string1` should do it. There might be a better way with list comprehensions, but this does the job too.

Explanation:

```
concat $ -- Flatten lists
  map (\char1 -> -- Iterate over each character of string1
    map (\char2 -> -- Iterate over each character of string2
      char1 : [char2] -- Add char1 to char2
    ) string2
  ) string1
```

Comment: This only works for exactly two strings, not a list of any size, which is what the question asks about. The OP's original snippet works just fine for two strings already. (also, `x:[y]` is just a weird way of writing `[x,y]`).

Comment: @amalloy Oh yeah. The `x:[y]` thing is because I'm relatively new (and rusty at that), but you're completely right (I guess I interpreted the question to mean strings of variable length). Would you recommend I delete this answer or does it provide educational value (I don't want to get downvoted into oblivion...)?

Comment: Not much in [haskell] gets downvoted to oblivion, so I wouldn't worry about it. If you think your answer is still instructive, you can leave it, possibly with an edit to clarify what problem it solves; or you can delete it. I downvoted because I think it's not useful, but two people upvoted, perhaps because it's a good desugaring of the list comprehension. It's entirely up to you.